# any css after this code not working , what is the problem in this css code, only in firefox?

Tags: html, firefox, css, cross-browser

Footer css after form's css is not working , what is the problem in this css code?

```
/*------------------------------------*\
    FORMS */

fieldset { padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; margin-bottom: 1.5em; }
label { display: block; cursor: pointer; }
    label:after { content:\": "; }
    label::after { content:\": "; }
input,textarea { font-family: inherit; font-size: 1em; line-height: 1.5; }
[placeholder] { cursor: pointer; }
    [placeholder]:active,[placeholder]:focus { cursor: text; }
fieldset > :last-child { margin: 0; }


footer {background:red; height:200px; width:200px}
```

jSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Aw239/

in jsfiddle example footer should be red background.

Comment: It is red when I look at it on chrome, what browser are you using?

Comment: Is it working in Firefox 5 for you?

Comment: why you use slash after the `content:` ?

Comment: `content:\": ";` is an error. You should have simply validated your CSS: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ (use CSS3 profile in advanced options)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least firefox Doesnt seem to understand this `label:after { content:\": "; }` i have no idea whats going on here but all i know is that it is the culprit. I've never actually used content properly.

But, remove those lines and everything runs smoothly.. ( OR reformat those two lines as Kyle showed and it should do it. )

Seems like it doesnt like to have closing semicolons in the same row with everything else

http://jsfiddle.net/Aw239/3/

Or.. get rid of the `\`'s ?

Comment: The problem is that backslash. It shouldn't be there.

Comment: @Eric But it's so cool and everyone else is doing it.. But seriously though it's existence is a big question mark to me.

Answer (score 1):

I formatted your CSS a bit and it seems to work in my FF5. http://jsfiddle.net/Aw239/2/

Comment: Yes now it's working. What was the problem? why it was working in chrome but not in firefox?

Comment: Is it mean that this code will not work in single line format?

Comment: No idea why it'd work like this and not like you had it, freakin' weird!

Answer (score 0):

It is red. Are you using IE8? Because you'll need to use the [HTML5 shim](http://code.google.com/p/html5shim/) if you want to style HTML5 elements.

[Does this work for you?](http://jsfiddle.net/Eric/Aw239/1/)

Comment: No your link not working in Firefox 5 but it's fine in Chrome